# Autolayout constraint view hierarchy error

Tags: ios, autolayout

After creating a tableview in code, I am trying to create a constraint setting the distance between the new tableview and a textview above it that exists in Storyboard. I can set constraints between the tableview and its superview but not between the tableview and this other element within the container.  The error is:

```
The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000c9be90 UITableView:0x7fe0cb126600.top == UITextView:0x7fe0ca128600.top + 12   (inactive)>
    When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled.  Would appreciate any suggestions on what to try.
```

This is how I am creating my constraints.

```
   _autocompleteTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    NSLayoutConstraint *leadingTableConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                 constraintWithItem:self.autocompleteTableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:
                                                 NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:20];

    NSLayoutConstraint *trailingTableConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                  constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.autocompleteTableView attribute:
                                                  NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:20];

    NSLayoutConstraint *topTableConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                 constraintWithItem:self.autocompleteTableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.subField attribute:
                                                 NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:12];


    NSLayoutConstraint *heightTableConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.autocompleteTableView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                           toItem:nil
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                       multiplier:1.0
                                                                         constant:300];


    [self.view addConstraints:@[leadingTableConstraint, trailingTableConstraint]];

     [self.autocompleteTableView addConstraints:@[heightTableConstraint]];
 //CRASHES ON NEXT LINE   
    [self.subField addConstraints:@[topTableConstraint]];
```

EDIT:

I have prevented the crash by calling addConstraints in the last line on self.view instead of self.subfield:

[self.view addConstraints:@[topTableConstraint]];//Instead of last line above

Now the code no longer throws exception, the tableview is not appearing at all.

Comment: You need to make sure the `subField` is already added to a view & `subField` should also be a descendant of `autocompleteTableView`, as the error message states. Also, preferably, you should add constraints in `viewDidLayoutSubview`.

Comment: The use case is the subfield is where you type something and the tableview then appears below as a suggestion box similar to Google.  So not sure how I could make subfield a subview of tableview.  Subfield is a subview of the superview, however, self.view.  I have added constraint to self.view instead of subField--see edit-- but now the tableview is no longer appearing at all.

Comment: You almost got it!, make sure you are adding the subview to the view controller's view and use `[self addConstraints:...` where self is the view controller's view.